# How to import all files at once pointed out by Dart Analysis?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

I just put some of my code from `a/b.dart` to `a/b1.dart` file and now I started getting  lot of errors on importing.

[image]

Is there any command or any other fix to import all `a/b1.dart` file in these files instead of manually opening each file and importing one by one.

I understand that a function or a property can be defined in more than two files and Dart can't make the right choice but if a function or property is defined in just one place, I think there must be some way to import it except searching for `a/b.dart` and replacing it with `a/b.dart` + `a/b1.dart` and then optimizing all imports.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I am aware, Plugins/Extensions for your specific IDE (for dart) can be found that will help you with this problem.

I would recommend using dartdev tools - [dartfix](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix)

Comment: `dart fix` won't help with imports.